# How to refresh an event changed into fullcalendar bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I change an event into fullcalendar bootstrap into modal then clik on event.

I change the title, but then click on submit modal button the event isn't refresh, I need F5 to reload page..

**How can I refresh my event changed automatically then click submit button?**

My code is:

```
$('#submitButtonEdit').on('click', function(e){
    // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
    e.preventDefault();
    doSubmitEdit();
});

function doSubmitEdit(){
    $("#createEventModalEdit").modal('hide');
    console.log($('#apptStartTime').val());
    console.log($('#apptEndTime').val());
    console.log($('#apptAllDay').val());
    console.log($('#id').val());

    var title = $('#patientName2').val();
    var start = $('#apptStartTime').val();
    var end = $('#apptEndTime').val();
    var allDay = $('#apptAllDay').val();
    var idEvent = $('#id').html();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        data: 'type=changetitle&title='+title+'&eventid='+idEvent,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.status == 'success'){
                var event_obj = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', idEvent);
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event_obj);
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
        }
    });

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
        title: $('#patientName2').val(),
        start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
        end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
        allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true"),
    }, true);
}




    <div id="createEventModalEdit" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
          <h3 id="myModalLabel1">Crear tarea</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="createAppointmentForm" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPatient">Tarea:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="patientName2" id="patientName2" tyle="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[&quot;Value 1&quot;,&quot;Value 2&quot;,&quot;Value 3&quot;]">
                    <input type="hidden" id="apptStartTime"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="apptEndTime"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="start">Inicio:</label>
                <div class="controls controls-row" id="start" style="margin-top:5px;">
                </div>
                <label class="control-label" for="end">Fin:</label>
                <div class="controls controls-row" id="end" style="margin-top:5px;">
                </div>

                <label class="control-label" for="start">Inicio:</label>
                <div class="controls controls-row" id="id" style="margin-top:5px;">
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"     id="submitButtonEdit">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
Get the event object
Open Modal, edit
update the event Object with the data from the modal
update Calendar with event Object
Send out Ajax
```

Remarks:

- `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', idEvent);` returns an
  array of events, even if filtered for one ID.
- `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {...` creates a new event on the timeline

Some changes:

```
function doSubmitEdit(){
    // get event object
    var event_obj_arr = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', idEvent);
    var event_obj = event_obj_arr[0];

    // edit
    $("#createEventModalEdit").modal('hide');
    console.log($('#apptStartTime').val());
    console.log($('#apptEndTime').val());
    console.log($('#apptAllDay').val());
    console.log($('#id').val());

    // update event object properties
    event_obj.title = $('#patientName2').val();
    event_obj.start = moment($('#apptStartTime').val());
    event_obj.end = moment($('#apptEndTime').val());
    event_obj.allDay = $('#apptAllDay').val() || false;
    // var idEvent = $('#id').html(); NEVER CHANGE THIS!

    // update calendar, you may put this line into success method
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event_obj);

    // post to server
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        data: 'type=changetitle&title='+title+'&eventid='+idEvent,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.status == 'success'){
                // nothing to do here
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

==> this is not yet tested!

Comment: I have used this with the line $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event_obj); but not works. The event not change then edit..  I'm trying $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id); and then $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); but this not appear again, is deleted.. how can get apply change without refresh page?